# Text Field in Actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, text

I am trying to create a text field manually from actionscript alone. I got parts of it but now i don't know how to give the fonts size and different fonts can somebody tell me how to go about this?

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < weekdaystringArray.length ; i++) 
{
weekdaystring.text = weekdaystringArray [i];
weekdaystring.x = 150;
weekdaystring.y = 994;
addChild (weekdaystring);
weekdaystring.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;


}
```

This is what I have so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a [TextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html) to the TextField with the [setTextFormat()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat%28%29) method.

```
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.font = "Courier";
format.size = 24;
// then inside your loop:
weekdaystring.setTextFormat(format);
```

Answer (score 0):

it need to apply a TextFormat to the TextFiled

```
var format:TextFormat = weekdaystring.defaultTextFormat;
format.font = "courier";
format.size = 24
weekdaystring.defaultTextFormat = format;
```